# How would one prove the pigeonhole principle with a SAT solver?

Tags: reference-request, logic, satisfiability, first-order-logic, proof-assistants

Suppose I wanted to find a proof of the pigeonhole principle or show that no  proof shorter than $L$ exists. I understand that proof-checking is in NP, so I could write a CNF formula that is satisfiable iff. such a proof exists. What I want to know is, how exactly would one do that? I understand I would assume a set of axioms about sets or something and also the axioms of first-order predicate calculus, and probably also modus ponens and stuff... but how exactly does one do something like this? Can anyone give a construction of such a CNF formula? References to papers or general explanations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

SAT solvers work in the *propositional calculus*, and usually accept as input a formula in *conjunctive normal form*. There are several different propositional variants of the pigeonhole principle; they are all contradictions, and the actual pigeonhole principle is their negation. One of them, which states that there is a one-to-one mapping from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$, is described in page 2 of this [book extract](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~rdewolf/resolutionlowerbound.pdf) (apparently Jukna's *Extremal Combinatorics*), where you can also find an exponential lower bound for refuting the pigeonhole principle in the resolution proof system.

(Reiterating, to prove that there is no one-to-one mapping from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$, we instead refute the formula stating that such a mapping does exist.)

SAT solvers are (almost) all based on the DPLL procedure (with some hacks such as clause learning), and so when they refute a statement, their transcript can be converted to a resolution refutation. Therefore the lower bound mentioned above shows that SAT solvers will have a hard time refuting the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Looks like the extract is from "Extremal Combinatorics: With Applications in Computer Science" by S. Jukna